# ¿Como puedo configurar correctamente nginx para heroku?

Tags: nodejs, nginx, heroku

Veran estoy intentando usar este [builpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx) para poder utilizar **NGINX** en mi aplicación de heroku, pero no se mucho sobre como configurar nginx. Y solo me base en algunos ejemplos pero no me funciona el archivo `nginx.conf.erb` correctamente.

Recientemente modifique mi archivo `nginx.conf.erb` y ahora me muestra el error **404** y me nuestra la pagina de error de heroku [no such app](https://www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/no-such-app.html).

Este es mi archivo **nginx.conf.erb**

```
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 8 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 10000 %>;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/xml+rss
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/javascript
        text/x-component;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    server_tokens off;

    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    output_buffers 1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;
    log_not_found on;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    upstream app_server {
        server nginxapp.herokuapp.com:443;
        server 127.0.0.1:<%= ENV["PORT"] %> backup;
    }
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginxapp:10m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";

    server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_min_length 512;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        keepalive_requests 100000;
        charset utf-8;

        root /public;

        location / {
            set $upstream_app app_server;
            proxy_cache nginxapp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_cache_control;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
            proxy_ssl_name nginxapp.herokuapp.com;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass https://$upstream_app;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es mi archivo **Procfile** para heroku

```
web: start-nginx-solo node app.js
```

Comment: Lograste resolverlo? Estoy intentando hacer lo mismo

Comment: @ArthuroAli si lo resolví, solo que olvide auto responder mi pregunta xd

Comment: Recuerdas como o tienes la config?

Comment: @ArthuroAli Si, deja auto respondo mi pregunta para que la copees y modifiques con tu app de heroku

Comment: @ArthuroAli te recomiendo que la configuración que deje ahí en mi respuesta la dejes tal cual, o por lo menos no modifiques el `listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Había olvidado auto responder mi pregunta después de un tiempo de haber resuelto mi problema xd*

Lo resolví de la siguiente manera(soy un poco malo explicando así que solo dejare la configuración de nginx)

```
daemon off;

worker_processes 8;

events {
    use epoll;
    multi_accept on;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections 10000;
}

http {
    charset utf-8;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/rss+xml
    application/xml+rss
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/javascript
    text/x-component;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    server_tokens off;

    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
    output_buffers 1 32k;
    postpone_output 1460;
    
        uuid4 $uuid;
    
    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service server=nginx method=$request_method path=$uri host=$host request_id=$uuid fwd=$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for dyno=web.<%= ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] %> connect=$upstream_connect_time service=$upstream_response_time status=$status bytes=$bytes_sent protocol=$scheme';
    access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
    error_log logs/nginx/error.log;
    log_not_found off;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    client_body_timeout 5;

    resolver 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 valid=60s;
    resolver_timeout 2s;

    upstream app_server {;
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    #proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=herokuapp:10m inactive=60m;
    proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";


    map $status $condition {
        ~^[23] 0;
        default 1;
    }

    server {
        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 9;
        gzip_min_length 512;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_types
        application/atom+xml
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/rss+xml
        application/xml+rss
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/javascript
        text/x-component;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        listen <%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
        listen [::]:<%= ENV['PORT'] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        keepalive_requests 100000;
        charset utf-8;

        root /public;

        location ~* / {
            set $app_server app_server;
            proxy_cache herokuapp;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_update;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Start $upstream_connect_time;
            proxy_set_header X-Request-ID $request_id;
            #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            #proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Via $http_via;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            #proxy_ssl_name $host;
            #proxy_ssl_verify off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_pass http://$app_server$request_uri;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
        }
        #       error_page 403 /html/403;
        #       error_page 404 /html/404;
        #       error_page 500 /html/500;
        #       error_page 502 /html/502;
        #       error_page 503 /html/503;
        #       error_page 504 /html/504;
    }
}
```

Lo que hice fue crear un localhost:8080 con NodeJS en heroku y pasárselo al upstream de nginx para que redireccionara al localhost:8080 de manera interna